# Error 2006 when importing a big SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have a problem importing a big SQL file (14,4GB) into my MySQL Database.
I've read all the threads about how to optimize the import with

> max_allowed_packet, net_buffer_length, foreign_key_checks, AUTOCOMMIT

I also did double check that the values were set.
Sadly I'm getting:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

And every solution I find suggests setting a higher max_allowed_packet value.

The Server I'm using has a 12Core Xeon, 128GB RAM and a SSD so Hardware should not limit the import..

I was also wandering if an import time of around 4 hours would be normal when importing SQL files with this size.